# Split Line at Points not Working ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gps, file-geodatabase

I have a GPS track in a FGDB that has an ID field with `A` or `B`. I converted these points into a line using `Points To Line`, grouping it by the ID field.

I then want to split the line at the same points I used to create the line. When I run the `Split Line at Point` tool I get an empty feature class as the return. Outputs are placed into a FGDB as well.

Comment: Have you tried Split Line at Vertices?

Answer (score 1):

Note that if the search radius parameter is not specified the tool use only one point to cut lines. [See arcmap help](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/split-line-at-point.htm).

> If this parameter is unspecified, the single nearest point will be used to split the line feature. If a radius is specified, all points within the radius will be used to split the line.

So you can either specify very minor value, or in your case to use the [split line at vertices](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/split-line-at-vertices.htm) tool.

Comment: Ideally, I should get a return of lines that is n-1 of the point features right? I get substantially fewer line features with split line at vertices tool. I will try specifying a small search radius. it may take awhile to run as I have 200,000+ points

Comment: I may have discovered the issue, one point is often many (when the GPS was stationary) and the tool has difficulty splitting this. When I run the Split at Vertices, the line is split when the position moves, hence fewer lines than points

Comment: It doesn't make sense. You have used GPS points (either cleaned or not) to create lines; hence the points are the vertices. Therefore in this case both tools should give the same result.

Comment: I think the problem may be having a zero length polyline

Comment: So it would be easy to fix -> select all polylines by length > 0, save as a new layer and use the tool.